# In R and ggvis, how to use LaTeX-typeset expressions in axes labels?

Tags: r, latex, ggvis

In R, when drawing a plot using `ggvis`, how to use LaTeX-typeset expressions in axes labels?

```
add_axis("x", title="$x_n$")
```

does not work.

Comment: `?expression` and `demo(plotmath)`

Comment: Checked;  I can tell it's definitely relevant info.  But still, I don't know how to get it to work in my application.

Comment: Yes, `ggvis` doesn't seem to interpret `expression` class.

Comment: So, there is no way to use LaTeX-typeset math expressions in plot labels made with `ggvis`?

Comment: If you can get mathjax into your output code there may be a way...